# VPS Configuration Recommendation for Angular2 and .Net App

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, configuration, vps

I and my team are developing an application that combining between Angular2 (front-end) and Web API ASP.NET (back-end).
We're working about VPS configuration for this app, but we are lack of knowledges on this field.
Can anyone help me to configure Cloud server Configuration which satisfies those requirements:

1. Website run well for minimum 500 visitors per day.
2. Support well for ASP MVC5 Web API.
3. How to configure to support Javascript and Angular 2 well.

   I am really highly appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1) Website run well for minimum 500 visitors per day. 
There is no issue related to Angular 2 It is simple framework running with web application

2) Support well for ASP MVC5 Web API.
again API is not issue for Angular 2 (either java or .NET) that depends on your lookout.

3) How to configure to support Javascript and Angular 2 well.
Here is gotcha if you thinking angular 2 is not javascript then you are wrong(although angular2 uses typescript but behind scene it is getting interpreted into javascript only)

so the moral of the story is nothing special will be require for Angular 2

Comment: Well I know that Angular 2 will be compiled to Javascript in order to run on browser. So the main purpose here is run a website which Angular2 is front-end and ASP.NET is back-end. Do you have any recommend for me to configure VPS to run it smoothly?

Comment: We do not have good knowledge about VPS configuration or Cloud Server.

Comment: so you mean to say qustion is more related to "VPS configuration or Cloud Server"  ?

Comment: both of them please!